# Redirects with a sinatra app on heroku

Tags: ruby, heroku, sinatra

I have a Tictactoe Game that i made for a course i am taking, and I have my app deployed to heroku. It works fine on my local host but, when I go to play it online it doesn't like the redirects that im using. redirect to('/status') which is where I have it going to check if there's a win or tie and if not it goes to have the ai or 2nd player choose a square . How do i go about fixing the issue or if someone can point me to a link that would be cool. Ive looked for a while now and cant seem to find it.

```
post '/game' do
choice = params[:choice].to_i
player_marker = players.current_player()

 if play_board.square_available?(choice - 1) == true
     play_board.board[choice - 1] = player_marker
     redirect to('/status')
 else
     erb :squares, :locals => {:p1 => players.player1, 
                              :p2 => players.player2, 
                              :invaild => "Hey #{players.current} #{choice} is already taken", 
                              :message2 => "Please choose again.", 
                              :current => players.current, 
                              :board => play_board.board, 
                              :type => players.type}
   end  
end

  2015-12-21T03:06:29.194376+00:00 app[web.1]: https://mmtictactoe.herokuapp.com /squares -> /style.css
  2015-12-21T03:06:32.382665+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST  path="/game" host=mmtictactoe.herokuapp.com request
 _id=b6b0abdb-783d-4111-99e4-244c1730179a fwd="75.89.86.120" dyno=web.1   connect=1ms service=18ms status=500 bytes=231
  2015-12-21T03:06:32.361241+00:00 app[web.1]: NoMethodError - undefined method `to' for #<Sinatra::Application:0x007f05bd
 0dae20>:
```

Comment: `it doesn't like the redirects` - what you mean by that?

Comment: @WandMaker when it gets the point where it is time to redirect to my status page in the code. It gives me an internal server error . Looking at the logs it gives me an undefined method to error which I dont get when running it locally it works perfectly when i play it locally this is snippet of the log https://mmtictactoe.herokuapp.com/squares -> /style.css
r]: at=info method=POST path="/game" host=mmtictactoe.he
"75.89.86.120" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=18ms statu
NoMethodError - undefined method `to' for #<Sinatra::App

Comment: and I've yet to learn testing the front end of my code only have done back end tests so I cant just make a test for it .....

Comment: It may be good idea to add the log snippet to your question so that people will know what is the issue you are facing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`redirect to` was introduced in Sinatra 1.2 in 2011. If you don't have this, you must be running a very old version of Sinatra on your Heroku server.

Take a [look here for getting started with Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-ruby-o#specify-ruby-version-and-declare-dependencies-with-a-gemfile), and make sure your Gemfile has Sinatra 1.4.x (latest at the time of this answer) specified:

```
gem 'sinatra', '~>1.4.0'
```

Comment: Thank you .... just learned how to deploy to heroku and the example gemfile we used must have been old because it was 1.1.0 changed it over to a newest one and presto !!! Thank you!! Still new to gem files and proc files